# why my spider is crawling 700+ items actually there are 245 items? how?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

why my spider is crawling 700+ items actually there are 245 items? how?

there are not more than 245 items but how my spider is scraping 700+ items even i use for loop to crawl only selected pages and tried to set my CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 244 in setting.py

any possible solution?

here is my code.

```
import scrapy
import json
from ..items import HmsItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class HmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hm'
    allowed_domains = ['hm.com']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(36,252, 36): #there is a diff of 36 on each next url
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = f"https://www2.hm.com/en_us/men/new-arrivals/view-all/_jcr_content/main/productlisting.display.json?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=model&offset=0&page-size={i}",
                method='GET',
                callback= self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # with open('initial.json', 'wb') as f:
        #     f.write(response.body)
        json_resp = json.loads(response.body)
        products = json_resp.get('products')
        for product in products:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=HmsItem())
            title = loader.add_value('title', product.get('title'))
            articleCode = loader.add_value('articleCode', product.get('articleCode'))
            category = loader.add_value('category', product.get('category'))
            src = loader.add_value('src', product.get('image')[0].get('src'))
            price = loader.add_value('price', product.get('price'))
            swatchesTotal = loader.add_value('swatchesTotal', product.get('swatchesTotal'))
            brandName =loader.add_value('brandName', product.get('brandName'))
            yield loader.load_item()
```

here is my setting.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'hms'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['hms.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'hms.spiders'
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 8
FEED = 'json'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 244
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 4.0
```

here is my items.py

```
import scrapy

class HmsItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    articleCode = scrapy.Field()
    category = scrapy.Field()
    src = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    swatchesTotal = scrapy.Field()
    brandName = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As scrapy can't take the params(querystring key value pairs) as parameter ,So we can't use it to make pagination using range funcction and for loop.

Actually your pagination method iterates the ResultSet and producing the duplicate items.

Alternative way is to get the correct output which is to inject the total items `243`
in the end point of the url where the `page-size=`  exists.

**Working code:**

```
import scrapy
import json
from ..items import HmsItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class HmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hm'
    #allowed_domains = ['hm.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        u="https://www2.hm.com/en_us/men/new-arrivals/view-all/_jcr_content/main/productlisting.display.json?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=model&offset=0&page-size=243"
        
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = u,
            method='GET',
            callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # with open('initial.json', 'wb') as f:
        #     f.write(response.body)
        json_resp = json.loads(response.body)
        products = json_resp.get('products')
        for product in products:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=HmsItem())
            title = loader.add_value('title', product.get('title'))
            articleCode = loader.add_value(
                'articleCode', product.get('articleCode'))
            category = loader.add_value('category', product.get('category'))
            src = loader.add_value('src', product.get('image')[0].get('src'))
            price = loader.add_value('price', product.get('price'))
            swatchesTotal = loader.add_value(
                'swatchesTotal', product.get('swatchesTotal'))
            brandName = loader.add_value('brandName', product.get('brandName'))
            yield loader.load_item()
```

**Output:**

```
'title': ['Reflective Running Gloves']}
2022-09-23 18:36:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www2.hm.com/en_us/men/new-arrivals/view-all/_jcr_content/main/productlisting.display.json?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=model&offset=0&page-size=243>    
{'articleCode': ['1104789002'],
 'brandName': ['H&M'],
 'category': ['men_sport_bottoms_leggingstights'],
 'price': ['$ 49.99'],
 'src': ['//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/40/a6/40a6eddd4f5cfa2f899b56c796022baeb23fe18f.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]'],
 'swatchesTotal': ['2'],
 'title': ['Running Tights']}
2022-09-23 18:36:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www2.hm.com/en_us/men/new-arrivals/view-all/_jcr_content/main/productlisting.display.json?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=model&offset=0&page-size=243>    
{'articleCode': ['1104789001'],
 'brandName': ['H&M'],
 'category': ['men_sport_bottoms_leggingstights'],
 'price': ['$ 49.99'],
 'src': ['//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/c5/69/c569b49c77761dc8e2690b476dbd38662e2157f9.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/style]'],
 'swatchesTotal': ['2'],
 'title': ['Running Tights']}
Finished Request
2022-09-23 18:36:11 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 431,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 47993,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 4.229539,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 23, 12, 36, 9, 21036),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 477132,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 243,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 258,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 23, 12, 36, 4, 791497)}
2022-09-23 18:36:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: so it means there is no need of pagination? and what if tomorrow this website adds some more products . let say 5 more and total will be 248  then i have to change my script again? is there any perfect way to get the total number of products first like using xpath ..  and make variable of that number and inject that variable at the end of my url?

Comment: @usman Abbasi,  Nothing to change except the total items. You also  have to change your range the way you are making the pagination if it increase the items after a few days if your pagination would work because to extract data from API depends  on their set of rules.I thinks it's not hard to change the items only just check the API

Comment: No, There is no any way to use xpath when you are scraping data via API

Comment: Yes,,no need of pagination any more